# Windows : Which process sent TCP/IP packet?

Tags: windows, networking

How do I find out which process has sent TCP/IP network packet?

Are there some tools that can easily do this? Like in Linux.

Comment: You can use ports to associate processes with TCP/IP traffic. `netstat` can be used for this purpose. For further information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows

Comment: Check this link from Microsoft for out-of-box tools https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nettracer/2010/08/02/have-you-ever-wanted-to-see-which-windows-process-sends-a-certain-packet-out-to-network/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the  **procmon** to see which processes send and receive network packets. Procmon is a tool in windows Sysinternals tools set,you can download from this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)